# Sort Multidimensional String Array Without Using Array.sort

Tags: java

I am new to Java, but to expand my knowledge of it.  Below is a class assignment that I'm having a very, very difficult time completing. I need to create a method that passes in a two dimensional string array and then sorts the array by the second element.

Method sortContacts()

- Declared as a public static method, it should take a
  two-dimensional String array as a parameter, and an integer value for
  the number of contacts in the array
- Returns nothing o Sorts the contents of the contact list given
  as a parameter using the lastName as the sorting field
- You may use any of the sorting mechanisms described in the text
  (bubble, insertion or selection)
- Key concept:    as you    implement the sort,    the trick is to
  identify the dimension for       the values you are    comparing and
  how they relate to the values    from    your loops.
- Hints:
- Do not rely on the array’s length for your loops, instead use the
  value from the number of contacts
- Your temp variable will be an
      array of size 3, `String[] temp = new String[3];`
- You will need to
          use the `string1.compareTo(string2)` method to compare two strings.

Sample data: (first name, last name, phone number)

```
String [][] contactsArray = { 

        {"Emily","Watson","913-555-0001"},
        {"Madison","Jacobs","913-555-0002"},
        {"Joshua","Cooper","913-555-0003"},
        {"Brandon","Alexander","913-555-0004"},
        {"Emma","Miller","913-555-0005"},
        {"Daniel","Ward","913-555-0006"},
        {"Olivia","Davis","913-555-0007"},
        {"Isaac","Torres","913-555-0008"},
        {"Austin","Morris","913-555-0009"}



public static void sortContact(String[][] contactsArray, int numContacts) {

    String[] temp = new String[3];
    String [] words = contactsArray[3];

    for(int i = 0; i < numContacts-1; i++)
    {
        int smallest = i;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < numContacts-1; j++) 
        {

            //Prints loop variables so I can see them before any action
            System.out.println("First: "+words[j]+" " +"Second "+words[i]);
            if(words[j].compareTo(words[i]) < 0)
                smallest = j;
        }

       //put the new minimum in the i-th position.

        //String temp = words[i];
        words[i] = words[smallest];
        words[smallest] = temp[i];
    }   
}
```

There are tons of examples for integer arrays but not a lot for string arrays,

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,:

```
 for(int i=0;i<numContacts;i++) {
        for(int j=i+1;j<numContacts;j++) {
            if(contactsArray [i][1].compareTo(contactsArray [j][1])>0) {
                String[] temp = contactsArray [i];
                contactsArray [i] = contactsArray [j];
                contactsArray [j] = temp;
            }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. Vinay that code worked great. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you go through the OOPs concept and how to implement them in Java. There are hundreds of books, articles and tutorials online for the same, like https://www.journaldev.com/12496/oops-concepts-java-example,  https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/oops-concepts/, etc.

As for the answer, you should create a class that extends `Comparable` interface to represent each of the rows in the 2D array. For example, create a class called `Contact` that implements `Comparable` interface. Implement the `compareTo` method from Comparable interface.
Then create a driver class that creates List of Person and call Collections.sort(list).

I have intentionally left the implementations to you as this is your assignment so that you learn by doing instead of somebody else doing them for you.

Please refer the following links for Comparable interface.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/comparable-vs-comparator-in-java/